# Is the phrase ENEMY OF ALLAH a metaphor?

Tags: allah

One of the Definition of enemy is a thing that harms or weakens something else.

Since none can harm or weaken Allah, can I conclude Allah has no enemies and thereby the phrase ***enemy of Allah*** a metaphor ?

This is further emphasized by Quran verse when translated.

> 5:33 Indeed, the penalty for those who wage war against Allah and His Messenger...

I'm asking this because arabs also used the phrase "may your face be covered with dust" metaphorically.

The last prophet has used words "get out enemy of Allah" while Exorcising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The english definition of 'enemy' does not matter. The word used in the Quran in context means: Someone who opposes, goes against, tries to be superior than.

So, no, it is not metaphorical. When the word 'enemy' is used, it means someone who is in opposition to Allah (i.e. Shaitan and Kuffar).